# Correlation as a likelihood measure

Tags: probability, correlation, interpretation, likelihood

Various forms of the correlation, e.g.,
$r =  \frac{\Sigma_i x_i * y_i}{\sigma_x  \sigma_y}$
or
$r = \frac{\Sigma_i (x_i-\bar{x}) * (y_i-\bar{y})}{\sigma_x  \sigma_y}$
are popular similarity measures in many applications.

Is there a probabilistic interpretation for this such that either $r$ or $r^2$ is an approximate likelihood for x and y coming from the same or similar distribution? i.e., if we have some form of $P_{\theta_1}(x)$ and $P_{\theta_2}(y)$, then $r$ is related to $P(\theta_1=\theta_2 | x,y)$?

I would guess that the correlation may be the first term in the approximation of some sort of a likelihood measure. But I am unable to arrive at such a model. Assuming $x$ and $y$ to come from a normal, and $\theta$ being the mean, it doesn't really derive that expression.

Comment: The "similarity" indexed by correlation refers to the degree to which high/low values in one distribution (relative to that distribution's mean and variance) are paired with high/low values from a second distribution (relative to that second distribution's mean and variance). Since high/low are relative, the two distributions can be very dissimilar in both mean and variance and still obtain a high correlation, so I don't think you can use the correlation as a means of comparing distributions.

Comment: @Mike, What if I let the scaling vary. Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are multivariate Gaussians, with a simple diagonal covariance. And then, I just test for the two means (which are vectors) are linearly related. i.e., $\mu_1 = s \mu_2$ for any scalar $s$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think PCA does something close to a Guassian noise model that comes close to a correlation measure in a multidimensional space.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a slight conceptual problem here: the likelihood is the quantity $P(x,y|\theta)$ as a function of $\theta$. But the correlation coefficient is a function of the data $x$ and $y$. The correlation coefficient is therefore by definition a "statistic" (a function of the data) and not a likelihood (a function of the parameters).

To put it another way, there are values of $\theta$ for which the probability of the observed correlation would be high, and other values of $\theta$ for which the observed correlation would be low. If you have a correlated Gaussian in mind, then the observed correlation might be unlikely due to the fact that the covariance matrix was either *more* dependent or less dependent than would be expected from the data.  (So the relationship between likelihood and $r^2$ will not even be monotonic unless $r^2=1$).  Of course, the *expected correlation coefficient* is monotonically related to the off-diagonal term in a bivariate Gaussian, but this doesn't make $r^2$ itself a proxy for likelihood.

It sounds like you're interested in a test of whether a particular correlation coefficient is likely to have been observed given that $x$ and $y$ were generated independently.  For this, you might want to perform a significance test on the value of the observed $r$ or $r^2$, which will tell you how *probable* it is that you observed that value given a particular model of the data.  The Wikipedia article on correlation coefficient [inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Inference) discusses a few common tests.